# Map in Python with string as key & Dictionary as value

Tags: java, python, dictionary

I'm a java developer , have a limited knowledge of python .

Currently i have a useCase that i need to create a map in python , that will contain entries like this :

```
{Name:Shivanshu,TV:LG,Fridge:"LG"}
{Name:Watson,TV:LG,Fridge:"LG"}
{Name:Rohan,TV:BrandA,Fridge:"BrandB"}
{Name:Rohan,WashingMachine:BrandA,CricketBat:"BrandC"}
{Name:Shivanshu, WashingMachine:BrandD, CricketBat:"BrandC"}
```

In java , i could have established it by using

```
map<String, map<String, String>>
```

I want to create & read & write such map in python , I know , i can get it by using string as a key & dictionary as value . But can someone please explain it with code , how we can leverage customMap like this in python .

Output : -

```
{Shivanshu,[TV:"LG",Fridge:"LG",WashingMachine:"BrandD", CricketBat:"BrandC"]}
{Rohan,[TV:"BrandA",Fridge:"BrandB",WashingMachine:"BrandA", CricketBat:"BrandC"]}
{Watson,[TV:"LG",Fridge:"LG"]}
```

How i'm reading the file :

```
with open('file.txt','r') as records:
    for eachRecord in records:
        Name = eachRecord.split("Name:",1)[1].split(",",1)[0]
        if(eachRecord.find("TV")!=-1):
            TV = eachRecord.split("TV:",1)[1].split(",",1)[0]
        if(eachRecord.find("Fridge")!=-1):
            Fridge = eachRecord.split("Fridge:",1)[1].split(",",1)[0]
        if(eachRecord.find("WashingMachine")!=-1):
            WashingMachine = eachRecord.split("WashingMachine:",1)[1].split(",",1)[0]
        if(eachRecord.find("CricketBat")!=-1):
            CricketBat = eachRecord.split("CricketBat:",1)[1].split(",",1)[0]
        # Here i want to create map & put all corresponding values in map .
        #Here i want to just store this map in another file.
```

Thanks .

Comment: Could you elaborate from where the data is coming from? a text/json file?

Comment: What, exactly, are you asking?

Comment: I'm maually reading data from file & want to create these key & value on the basis of strings retrieved from file .

Comment: Can you provide a few lines of file please ?

Comment: OK, *and what exactly is the problem*?

Comment: Edited the question with necessary details & how i'm doing it .

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga , is problem-statement still unclear ?

Comment: @WArnold , let me know , if anything else information is required ?

Comment: `result[name] = {"TV":TV, "Fridge":Fridge}`?

Comment: Please have a look in question again , have modified it a bit . Thanks .

Answer (score 1):

It remains unclear whether your file is in json format or not.

I'm assuming not.

```
import json

data = []
with open('file.txt', 'r') as records:
    for line in records:
        formatted_line = line.replace('"', '').replace(
            '{', '{"').replace('}', '"}').replace(':', '":"').replace(',', '","')
        data.append(json.loads(formatted_line))

print(data)
```

This way data will be a list (contiguous array) of dictionaries.

Assuming you always have a name and no duplicate names, your final result should look something like :

```
dict_ = dict()

for x in data:
    dict_[x['Name']] = {'TV': x['TV'], 'Fridge': x['Fridge']}

print(dict_)
```

Your question remains unclear still. I would give this a shot.